# How to get access on a StandardListItem in a sap.m.List?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I create a sap.m.List with some StandardListItem's.

```
    var citems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                var citem = new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                        {
                        type: "Active",
                        tap : function() {alert(data.results[i].ID) 
// ?????},
                        title: data.results[i].NAME,
                        description: data.results[i].ID
                        });
                citems.push(citem);
            } //fill the citems array

            var oList = new sap.m.List({
                headerText : "Customers",
                setGrowingScrollToLoad: true,
                items : citems,
                press: function(e) {
                console.log(oList.getSelectedItems());
                },
                itemPress: // ??????
            });
            oList.placeAt("content");
```

Now I want, that a function is called when I tap on an item, which is in the list. But everything I tried doesent worked. 
I get an alert, which says that the "ID" which I placed in the description of an item isn't defined.

So, does anybody know, how I get access to the decription of the taped item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your Tap event

```
tap: function (e) {
            var msg = 'The item selected was: ' + this.getTitle() + '\nDescription: ' + this.getDescription();
            alert(msg);
      },
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/connecttobn/2y6emero/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you mean, with the <frame> ?

Comment: iframe is a running script added for reference.. you can run the script live . See code here http://jsfiddle.net/connecttobn/2y6emero/

Comment: Thats genius! In the function(e) { ....} I can call another function. Before your answer I wrote: tap: getDetail( this.Description );     Now its clear why it does'nt worked. Thank you